# Golang Read JSON from S3 into struct in memory

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, unmarshalling

I have a JSON file in S3 that takes the format of the following struct:

```
type StockInfo []struct {
    Ticker         string `json:"ticker"`
    BoughtPrice    string `json:"boughtPrice"`
    NumberOfShares string `json:"numberOfShares"`
}
```

and I want to read it into a struct value from S3. In python the code would look something like this:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=os.environ["BucketName"], Key=os.environ["Key"])
fileContents = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(fileContents)
```

However I'm kinda stuck on how to make this happen in Go. I've gotten this far:

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

type StockInfo []struct {
    Ticker         string `json:"ticker"`
    BoughtPrice    string `json:"boughtPrice"`
    NumberOfShares string `json:"numberOfShares"`
}

func init() {
    // loads values from .env into the system
    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Print("No .env file found")
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    // Store the PATH environment variable in a variable
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    s3Client := s3.New(sess)
    bucket := "ian-test-bucket-go-python"
    key := "StockInfo.json"

    requestInput := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }
    result, err := s3Client.GetObject(requestInput)
        if err != nil {
             fmt.Println(err)
        }
    fmt.Println(result)
```

which returns to me the body/object buffer, but im not sure how to read that into a string so I can marshal it into my struct. I found this code in a similar question:

```
    requestInput := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }

    buf := new(aws.WriteAtBuffer)
    numBytes, _ := *s3manager.Downloader.Download(buf, requestInput)
    tr := tar.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
```

but I get the following errors:

```
not enough arguments in call to method expression s3manager.Downloader.Download
    have (*aws.WriteAtBuffer, *s3.GetObjectInput)
    want (s3manager.Downloader, io.WriterAt, *s3.GetObjectInput, ...func(*s3manager.Downloader))

multiple-value s3manager.Downloader.Download() in single-value context
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? kinda frustrating how hard it seems to do this compared to python.

Comment: Agree on the comparison to Python comment, wow.

Comment: @jarmod except that the Python code in its presented form can only be used for throwaway scripts, and is completely useless in industrial applications where error handling and precise control over resources used to carry out a task is paramount.

Comment: @kostix I mean, it's not really only used for throwaway scripts, that is the widely accepted way to read a JSON from s3 into a dictionary in python. it is widely used in production. maybe not for your specific use cases, but for countless others.

Comment: That wasn't my point, @DBA108642 ;-) I wanted to highlight that in the indicated piece of code each call (`.methodname()`) is able to blow up with an exception (the type of which you do not know), and god knows what happens if, say, `os.environ[somekey]` returns an empty string which gets passed to the call. I mean, it's fine for throwaway script but if we add _proper_ error handling, the resulting code won't be too much different from that written in Go in terms of verboseness (of course if we won't resort to "one big wrapping `try…catch`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to do it with the following code:

```
    requestInput := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }

    result, err := s3Client.GetObject(requestInput)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer result.Body.Close()
    body1, err := ioutil.ReadAll(result.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    bodyString1 := fmt.Sprintf("%s", body1)

    var s3data StockInfo
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(bodyString1))
    err = decoder.Decode(&s3data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("twas an error")
    }

    fmt.Println(s3data)
```

Comment: The code appears to be correct; please accept your own answer (that's OK).

Comment: I plan to, they just force you to wait a couple days.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using `json.Unmarshal`

> besed on `aws-sdk-go-v2`

```golang
...
params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(s3Record.S3.Bucket.Name),
    Key:    aws.String(s3Record.S3.Object.Key),
}
result, _ := client.GetObject(context.TODO(), params)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer result.Body.Close()

// capture all bytes from upload
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(result.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var temp StockInfo
if err = json.Unmarshal(b, &temp); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ftm.Println("res: ",b)
```